# How do I remove light from materials in 3DS Max?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

[image: Why my materials all with light?]

Why are all my materials with light? How to make it dark?

Comment: Are you self-illuminating those materials? Generally, it depends on your specular level and glossiness to determine how your material interacts with light.

Comment: How to know about self-illuminating?  specular level and glossiness are 0

Comment: Ok, I have found it, it was enabled (selected color), I have the white diffuse texture, but I want to color it in 3d max...